# Different code to display at different times of the day. How to Specify the exact time in minutes and hours?

Tags: php, date, time

What if I want the code to run at an even more specific time each day? eg:

```
<?php
$h = date('G');
$d = date('w'); 
$m = date('i');    
if ($d == 5 && $h = 23 && $m >= 0015 && $m <= 0020)
{
$byes = false; echo $b;
}
else if ($d == 5 && $h >= 20)
{
$byes = true; echo $b;
}
?>
```

$b is a list. From 8pm on Friday, the list should display on the site. However from 23:15 until 23:20 the list should go down.

I've been trying for ages. It works with the rounded hoursm but how do I include the minutes?

Comment: why are you splitting into hours and minutes? Why not just compare the complete time?

Comment: `$time = strtotime('Friday 8pm');` will give you the timestamp for 8pm next Friday

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lays here:

```
if ($d == 5 && $h = 23 && $m >= 0015 && $m <= 0020)
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php states that date('i') gives you the minutes with leading zeros. For integer comparison, you want $m=intval(date("i")); to remove the leading zeros and make it an integer. If the problem still occurs, try parsing all of the date()-values as integer.

If this doesn't work, try outputting all the values.
echo date("i") and other stuff to really see what gets compared how.
Also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php to output the types of the variables.

Hope I could help. Give me a thumbs up :)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. Doesn't seem to be working. How do I give a thumbs up though? :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by

```
<?php

$d = date('w');
$time = date("G:i");
$breakstart ="23:15";
$breakend ="23:20";

if ($d == 5 && $time>=$breakstart && $time <= $breakend) {
$byes = false; echo $b;
}
elseif ($d == 5 && $time>="20:00") {
$byes = true; echo $b;    
}

?>
```